# SignalR connections skewing response time in IIS using ARR

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, arr

We are using application request routing with 5 servers running IIS 7.5 and have just recently implemented a messaging system using SignalR in our application.

The SignalR connections are working as we expect (with the only drawback being that a message sent from one server doesn't get activated on the other 4).

The problem(?) we are having is that the Response Time of some requests on IIS that are shown in the load balancer (ARR) are coming up as 2-3 minutes sometimes, which I am assuming are because of connections using something like long-polling.

Our ARR is set to load balance using lowest response time, but it seems like this metric will be completely incorrect because of these SignalR connections. Is there any way to fix these connections so they don't get used in the ARR calculation for response time? Are we stuck having to move the SignalR messages to a separate server to avoid this type of thing (which admittedly would solve other things as well)?

Answer (score 2):

I think the article below will help you. Try setting the "response buffer threshold" to 0 in ARR

http://matthewmanela.com/blog/using-signalr-in-an-arr-cluster/